# How to create symlink on OSX?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

I would like to have 2 folders with almost the same content - all subfolder, all files should be the same except 2 files. If I change something in one folder (file content, create new file, delete some file), then it should be changed in the second folder except these 2 files. Can I achieve the same with symlinks? How to create them?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by wiping out the secondary folder, and making the secondary folder a symlink to the primary storage folder.

To create a symlink in OSX, open a terminal window, and do the following:

```
cd <primary_directory_path_parent_directory>
ln -s <path_to_secondary_directory> <primary_directory_name>
```

This should take care of what you're looking for.

Comment: But how to handle these 2 files, which should be different in these 2 folders?

Comment: You can't handle the 2 files requirement with symlinks.

Comment: Give them new names.

Comment: @MattVoboril, they **must** be the same.

Comment: the only other option for you is to symlink the individual files that can be linked, and just not the other 2